# BeautifulSoup and HTML page source don't match - how to remove nth </table> in list of BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull play-by-play data from www.basketball-reference.com.  Specifically: http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/HOU/2014_games.html for the Houston Rocket's play by play data.  I've been working pretty steadily for the last couple of hours and I've almost found a way to get all the data I need.

I start on the Houston Rockets season page and pull the links for all the games, and am trying to run for loops to visit each page and download the information I need into lists. Below is my code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import urllib
import csv

#get all links
url = 'http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/HOU/2014_games.html'
file_pointer = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(file_pointer)

#find links within site
links = soup.findAll('a',text='Box Score')

#create vector full of all links
answer =[]
for link in links:
    answer.append(link.parent['href'])

#add create full link with pbp
final = []
for item in answer:
    final.append('http://basketball-reference.com/boxscores/pbp' + item[10:])


# create empty lists
soup =[]
table = []
headers = []
rows = []

# for item in final do the soup
for item in final:
    soup.append(BeautifulSoup(urlopen(item)))


# for item in soup find the table
for item in soup:
    table.append(item.find('table', attrs={ "class" : "no_highlight stats_table"}))
```

The problem appears when I create the `soup` variable. If I go to the website for the first game (http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/pbp/201310300HOU.html) and pull up the source page, the beginning of the table I want to pull is :

```
<table class="no_highlight stats_table">
<tr id="q1">
<th colspan="6">1st Quarter</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

However, when I pause my code and `print soup[0]` it spits out this:

```
<table class="no_highlight stats_table">
<tr id="q1">
<th colspan="6">1st Quarter</th></tr></table></td>
```

So instead of grabbing the table I want, it grabs this short, useless chunk of code. I ran the BeautifulSoup code through a HTML compiler, and if I remove the `</table>` above, then the table runs as it should.

The problem is, this is the 27the occurrence of `</table>` in the code and I don't know how to go into the class BeautifulSoup to remove that `</table>`.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Where in the code are you attempting to `print soup[0]`?

Comment: I removed that part when I typed this up.

Comment: Agreed, but it is not clear how your expected results and the one you are getting are different. It is important to know at what point in the code you are trying to print the variable.

Comment: Well, I would put the      print soup[0] after the soup.append() line.